# Blank padding under the subsection heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I have a subsection named "Resources" defined after a section as \subsection{Resources}. I am getting unwanted blank padding right underneath the heading of the subsection in the pdf. Below the image illustrates my problem. Any help to get rid of that will be appreciated.

```
\subsection{Resources}

\indent There are a total of 4 different game broadcasts used for the purpose of this study.
```

[image: Blank padding underneath subsection]

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `\noindent`. However, there's most likely something odd *following* what you've posted that is causing the page to be stretched out like that. You'll need to show more content (both code and output).

Comment: Just in case, try the `\raggedbottom` directive in the preamble (default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Hi, the \raggedbottom did the trick. Thanks. Does it mean that i have to include it at each subsection?

Comment: @user183826: `\raggedbottom` is called within the preamble and will have a global effect on your document, resulting in varied text block sizes depending on the content of your document. You should consider providing more detail about what follows at the top of page 5.

Comment: At the top of page 5, i have a new section declaration. \section{sectionname}